# Cumulative grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = 
     name  amount  date
 0     A     10      1
 1     B     15      1
 2     A      5      2
 3     C      7      3
 4     A      8      4
 5     B     10      4
 6     C     11      4
```

and I would to do a cumulative sum along names and dates, I mean, my desired result with this example will be:

```
df_result = 
     name  amount  date
 0     A     10      1
 1     B     15      1
 2     A     15      2
 3     B     15      2
 4     A     15      3
 5     B     15      3
 6     C      7      3
 7     A     23      4
 8     B     25      4
 9     C     18      4
```

I want to show the accumulated value over the time periods represented by the date column, for example, for the case of A, its value in period 1 is 10, in 2 it is 5, in 3 it is 0 (because it does not appear) and in 4 it is 8, so that in the df_result that accumulation is shown. C does not appear until period 3 because it has no value until that period

I've tried different combinations of groupby, cumsum, even stack, but I can't achieve anything close to that.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how you get from your input to the output? Why do you end up with more rows for instance? It kind of looks like you've "padded" date 3... but then I'd probably expect date 1 to have a C with 0 in that case...

Comment: You probably looking for this `df.groupby(by=['name','date']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().reset_index()`

Comment: Of course @JonClements: I want to show the accumulated value over the time periods represented by the date column, for example, for the case of A, its value in period 1 is 10, in 2 it is 5, in 3 it is 0 (because it does not appear) and in 4 it is 8, so that in the df_result that accumulation is shown. C does not appear until period 3 because it has no value until that period. I hope I explained it well

Comment: @Á.Garzón please [edit] that into your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it helps:

```
>>> df.groupby(by=['name','date']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().reset_index()
  name  date  amount
0    A     1      10
1    A     2      15
2    A     4      23
3    B     1      15
4    B     4      25
5    C     3       7
6    C     4      18
```

Another answers as @Jon described in the comments with the pivot that's draws you close what you shown.

```
>>> df = df.pivot('date', 'name', 'amount').fillna(0).stack().groupby(level=1).cumsum().astype('int')[lambda v: v != 0].reset_index()
```

Rename the last columns as that will be zero .

```
>>> df.rename(columns={0: 'amount'}, inplace=True)
>>> df
   date name  amount
0     1    A      10
1     1    B      15
2     2    A      15
3     2    B      15
4     3    A      15
5     3    B      15
6     3    C       7
7     4    A      23
8     4    B      25
9     4    C      18
```

Comment: Yeees!! Thanks you very much!! It's perfect!

Comment: @Á.Garzón great... but the output shown here isn't the same as the output you say you want in the question? I'm confused...

Comment: @Á.Garzón, Glad it helped :-)

Comment: Ouch... @JonClements has right... I'm not sure if this is the perfect solution, but almost it's a good improvement... 
I'm going to test my code now in case this solution serves even if it's not exactly the one required

Comment: @Á.Garzón something like `df.pivot('date', 'name', 'amount').fillna(0).stack().groupby(level=1).cumsum().astype('int')[lambda v: v != 0].reset_index()` will get you close - I'm not sure it's that efficient though... pygo - if you want to run with that - feel free :)

Comment: @JonClements, let me test it out :-) thnx

Comment: @JonClements, that's matches the earlier desired output by OP, Shall i add that or you can post that along? i have added for now if you will post i'll remove that.

Comment: @JonClements yes, that is exactly what I want, however, when I run this I get the following error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape :(

Comment: I was afraid of that... didn't think your actual data would have the same characteristics as your example data :).... pygo: yeah... it's fine - you can have it... I wasn't sure about it nor had time to test it... so... appears it doesn't work for OP's data though... :)

Comment: @JonClements I'm so sorry, I've forgotten that I had rows with the same name  and date but different amount, so I've used a groupby to solve that and apply your code and I think that now it's working as I want. Sincerely, many thanks to both :)

Comment: @Á.Garzón,  great, what was the combined solution which worked?

Comment: Finally I've used the pivot solution given by @JonClements after a groupby by date in order to not having problems when using pivot. `df= df.groupby(['name', 'date']).sum().reset_index()`;   `df= df.pivot('date', 'name', 'amount').fillna(0).stack().groupby(level = 1).cumsum().astype('int')[lambda v: v != 0].reset_index()`;   `df.rename(columns = {0: 'amount'}, inplace = True)`